# Spring Transaction Rolback Error

Tags: java, database, spring, jakarta-ee

I have following methods and after invoking `callBothMethodInvocation()` method, I am expecting user inserted when execution of `insertUser()` will be roll back because of exception ocurred at insertUserWithException(). However whenI check the Database User table, entity exists in table.
What am I missing ? 
I have found similar problem http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?108015-JDBC-Transaction-inner-methods-and-rollback but cannot find a the exact solution.

```
@Transactional(rollbackFor=Exception.class)    
private void callBothMethodInvocation() throws Exception {
    insertUser();
    insertUserWithException();      
}


public void insertUserWithException() throws Exception{
    throw new Exception("fake exception for rollback");
}

@Transactional(rollbackFor=Exception.class) 
public void insertUser(){
    int id = (int) (System.currentTimeMillis()%1000);
    System.out.println("Insert user id:"+id);
    User user = new User(id,"Test",22);
    testDao.insertUser(user);
}
```

**Spring Configuration:**

```
<beans 
    xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop" 
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx" 
    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xmlns:ehcache="http://ehcache-spring-annotations.googlecode.com/svn/schema/ehcache-spring"   
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-2.5.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-2.5.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-2.5.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-2.5.xsd
        http://ehcache-spring-annotations.googlecode.com/svn/schema/ehcache-spring http://ehcache-spring-annotations.googlecode.com/svn/schema/ehcache-spring/ehcache-spring-1.2.xsd"
    default-lazy-init="false">


    <context:component-scan base-package="com.mkyong" />

    <context:property-placeholder location="config.properties" />

    <bean id="helloBean" class="com.mkyong.common.HelloWorld">
        <property name="name" value="Ahmet" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="person" class="com.mkyong.common.Person">
        <constructor-arg type="java.lang.String" value="DefaultName"/>
        <constructor-arg type="int" value="30"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="jmxAdapter" class="org.springframework.jmx.export.MBeanExporter" lazy-init="false">
        <property name="beans">
            <map>
                <entry key="SPRING:Name=TestRun">
                    <ref bean="jmxService" />
                </entry>
            </map>
        </property>
        <!-- managemethods property starts -->
        <property name="assembler">
            <bean
                class="org.springframework.jmx.export.assembler.InterfaceBasedMBeanInfoAssembler">
                <property name="managedInterfaces">
                    <value>com.mkyong.jmx.JmxCoreComands</value>
                </property>
            </bean>
        </property>
        <!-- managemethods property ends -->
    </bean>


    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="${db.driver}"/>
        <property name="url" value="${db.url}"/>
        <property name="username" value="${db.username}"/>
        <property name="password" value="${db.password}"/>      
    </bean>

    <!-- Cache Mekanizmasi -->  
    <ehcache:annotation-driven />
    <ehcache:config cache-manager="cacheManager">
        <ehcache:evict-expired-elements interval="60" />
    </ehcache:config>
    <bean id="cacheManager" class="org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="configLocation"  value="classpath:ehcache.xml"/>
    </bean>

    <!-- Aspect Oriented Performance Log Mekanizmasi -->
    <aop:aspectj-autoproxy />
    <bean id="performanceLogger" class="com.mkyong.util.PerformanceLogger" />

</beans>
```

**added following configuration:**

```
<bean id="txManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="myEmf" />
</bean>
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="txManager" />
```

**pom.xml**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.mkyong.common</groupId>
  <artifactId>SpringExample</artifactId>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>SpringExample</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Spring framework -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
        <artifactId>ojdbc14</artifactId>
        <version>10.2.0.3.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.googlecode.ehcache-spring-annotations</groupId>
      <artifactId>ehcache-spring-annotations</artifactId>
      <version>1.2.0</version>
    </dependency>



  </dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: can you share your spring configuration for this?  it sounds like the `@Transactional` isn't being picked up

Comment: Added spring configuration.

Answer (score 0):

it looks like you don't have a TransactionManager configured or the ability to pick up `@Transactional`.

try adding `<tx:annotation-driven/>` and a `JpaTransactionManager` bean called `transactionManager`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable Spring transactions in context.xml

```
<tx:annotation-driven />
<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
</bean>
```

here is a working test

```
class X {
    @Autowired
    DataSource ds;

    @Transactional(rollbackFor = Exception.class)
    public void insert() throws Exception {
        new JdbcTemplate(ds).update("insert into t1 (c1) values ('1')");
        throw new Exception();
    }
}

@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration("/transactions.xml")
public class Transactions {
    @Autowired
    X x;

    @Test
    public void test() throws Exception {
        x.insert();
    }
}
```

transactions.xml

```
xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.2.xsd
        ">
<context:annotation-config />

<bean class="X" />

<tx:annotation-driven />

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
</bean>

<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost/test" />
    <property name="username" value="root" />
    <property name="password" value="root" />
</bean>
```

Comment: added but rollback does not performed succesfully.

Comment: are you using spring-jpa?

Comment: OK, it seems you are using JdbcTemplate directly, try to change JpaTransactionManager to DataSourceTransactionManager like in my answer

Comment: I have added what you typed in my spring configuration but it does not work.

Comment: My application is J2SE Application.

Comment: I have found an interesting thing that, When I called insert() method individually, rollback works properly,but my case is different in that insertUser() method and insertUserWithException() method called in other method (Transactional). Exception occured in insertUserWithException() does not trigger rollback in inserUser() method.

Comment: I think I have not explain my problem clearly, but have found similar problem http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?108015-JDBC-Transaction-inner-methods-and-rollback